# How to find line followed by known string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How do you find text, if you only know string on line it is followed by?
Example:

```
...
some unimportant text
Line I want
text text String_I_know
some more text
```

my approach was rather simple, using sed I tried to cut the text at known string, then list only last 2 lines  and then only first line:

```
echo $MyString | sed 's/String_I_know*//' | tail -2 | head -1
```

But it would seem sed does not work well on text containing \n characters.
Is there any way around?

Edit: Was already answered, but adding little extra info to avoid confusion with other grep related question. Here, I don't need to list one line before every occurrence of string, as I know it's there only once (or I don't care for other occurrences) Therefore, use of

```
echo "$MyString" | grep -B1 String_I_know | head -1
```

is prefered, since it should work also on non-POSIX systems

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for clear question + showing your efforts in your question, keep it up. Also try to search forums here you may get some answers(sometimes related sometimes exact too). Enjoy learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` lets you print context along with matched line(s). Then you just need to ignore the matched line.

```
echo "$MyString" | grep -B1 String_I_know | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you here.

Let's say following is my variable.

```
echo "$var"
some unimportant text
Line I want
text text String_I_know
some more text
```

Then following is the code.

```
echo "$var" | awk '/String_I_know/{print prev} {prev=$0}'
Line I want
```